# Is There a Max Number of In-Transit UDP Packets?

Tags: udp, packet-loss

I am sending some data over UDP from client to server using [sendto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto). I noticed all the data was not being received. I began logging (printing) each packet sent on the client, and just the act of doing that fixed the problem. That showed me that it must be a timing issue, so I stopped logging them on the client and logged them being received on the server instead, and it only received 130 of the packets. It appeared that that somehow after that number, packets were no longer being received. To test this theory, I made it so on the client, it would sleep after 129 or so packets and then continue to send and repeat. This indeed allowed ALL the packets to send correctly.

I can not find anything on Google about this. Is the NIC having some sort of slot limit? Like a buffer being filled up too fast? I am running this locally on loopback (127.0.0.1). I know UDP packets can be dropped, but this happening on loopback is quite strange. Especially the circumstances with it being only if I sent 130+ all consecutively. Hopefully someone here knows the cause of this behavior.

UPDATE: Found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887797/correct-way-to-send-a-sequence-of-udp-datagrams) when browsing. This is almost identical to my problem

Comment: There's no way to tell where the problem is with the limited information you've provided.  But it appears to be a problem with your PC.  That is off topic here.

Comment: Often, your application will be sending faster than the bandwidth on your network interface, and the packets get dropped inside your PC before going out. UDP cannot deal with that, but TCP will slow down to the proper bandwidth.

Comment: @RonTrunk ...what are you talking about?

Comment: @RonMaupin This seems to be the most logical explanation of what is occurring, thank you. How would you suggest dealing with/handling this issue?

Comment: What goes on inside your host is off-topic here. I have seen at least one question on [so] about exactly this problem, and the OP solved it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no limit in UDP for "in-flight" datagrams. There's no tracking, so there can't be a limit.

UDP is an "unreliable" transport-layer protocol, ie. UDP makes no effort to ensure delivery to the destination. Any number of datagrams can be lost on the way due to congestion, misrouting, packet filtering, ...

In your case there's seems to be some kind of filter triggered by bandwidth or packet frequency - you'd need to ask your network admins or the ISP(s).

If you need reliable delivery then UDP isn't for you. There's TCP, of course, or RUDP, or you could track delivery on the application layer - that however is off-topic here as are programming or host configurations/issues.

PS: closing the question as you're only really interested in the host specifics, not the network protocol as such

Comment: "In your case there's seems to be some kind of filter triggered by bandwidth or packet frequency - you'd need to ask your network admins or the ISP(s)."

I'm testing on localhost, as I specified in my question. So definitely not.

I am planning on using this for VOIP and screenshare by the way. As I said, I understand that UDP will have packetloss, but the fact that it is occuring on loopback surprised me. Have you seen Ron Maupin's comment on my question? If so, what do you make of that? It seems like the most logical explanation of what's going on

Comment: Well, the implementation of the loopback virtual interface is host-specific, making it off-topic here. You might have more luck on [so] where there are many network-savvy programmers. They'd want to see some code though.

Comment: Everything has limits, even loopback. As everyone has said, UDP is not a reliable transport. It's "fire and forget"; no packet is guaranteed to go anywhere.